# How to calculate an element-wise quotient of two data frames?

Tags: r, dataframe

```
> A <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3), y = c(4,5,6), z = c(7,8,9))
> B <- data.frame(x = c(1,1,1), y = c(2,2,2), z = c(3,3,3))
> A
  x y z
1 1 4 7
2 2 5 8
3 3 6 9
> B
  x y z
1 1 2 3
2 1 2 3
3 1 2 3
```

What I would like to do is calculate a new data frame C which is the defined as:

```
C[i,j] := A[i,j] / B[i,j]
```

for all coordinates i,j possible.

Is there a **clean and quick** way to do it *without resorting to loops* and *without referencing individual columns or rows*?

(Application of data.table, plyr is fine)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple: do `A/B`:

```
R> C <- A/B
R> C
  x   y       z
1 1 2.0 2.33333
2 2 2.5 2.66667
3 3 3.0 3.00000
R>
```

R *really* is a vectorised language.

Comment: how awkward ... that is actually true. I thought I already gave that a try. thanks anyway ;)